# How can I disable vue.js watcher while created/mounted methods are yet to be finished?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I would like to disable watcher, so it doesn't trigger certain watcher when **created** or **mounted** finish and enable it after these done. What is the proper way to achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without seeing what you are doing, it's quite difficult to know exactly what you are trying to achieve. Generally, you should not be handling `watchers` yourself, so it's worth taking a look at your code to see if there is a better solution. With that said, it is possible to apply a `watcher` at runtime, you can do it  inside the `mounted` hook, after you have `initialised` everything else:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  created() {
    // this won't fire the watcher as it hasn't been applied yet
    this.foo = 'foo'
  },
  mounted() {
    // Apply watcher after all other initialization is done
    this.applyFooWatcher()
  },
  methods: {
    applyFooWatcher() {
      this.$watch('foo', function(newVal, oldVal) {
        console.log('Foo changed from ' + oldVal + ' to ' + newVal);
      });
    }
  },
  data: {
    foo: ''
  }
})
```

Here's the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fo0vmxf6/